# Showing an integral is in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lp-spaces

> Let $0<a<1$ and $f\in L^1([0,1])$. Show $g(x)=\int_0 ^x\frac{1}{(x-t)^a}f(t)dt$ exists a.e. in $[0,1]$ and $g\in L^1([0,1])$.

Using Fubini,
$$\int_0 ^1 \vert  g(x) \vert dx=\int_0 ^1 \int_0 ^x\frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^a}dtdx=\\\int_0 ^x \bigg( \int_0 ^1\frac{1}{(x-t)^a}dx\bigg)dt=\int_0 ^x\frac{1}{(1-a)(x-t)^{a-1}}\bigg\vert_0 ^1dt\\=\int_0 ^x\bigg(\frac{1}{(1-a)(1-t)}-\frac{1}{(1-a)(-t)^{a-1}}\bigg)dt\\=\bigg[-\log(1-t)/(1-a)- \frac{1}{(1-a)(2-a)(-t)^{a-2}}\bigg]\bigg\vert _0 ^x\\=-\log(1-x)/(1-a)-\frac{1}{(1-a)(2-a)(-x)^{a-2}}$$

I beleive this shows that $g$ is in $L^1$, but what's needed to show it exists a.e.?

**Update** My approach is flawed and I don't have an idea of how to proceed.

Comment: Apart from forgetting $f$, note that the double integral after the second equal sign is ill-formed since one integrates from $t=0$ to $t=x$ after having integrated from $x=0$ to $x=1$. It seems much more caution could be brought to this try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:X \rightarrow [0, +\infty]$ be a measurable function and $A$ a measurable subset of $X$. If measure of a set $C = \{x \in A : f(x) = +\infty\}$ is strictly positive, then $\int_A \! f \, \mathrm{d}\mu = +\infty.$

Contraposition gives us that for $g$ to exist almost everywhere, it is enough that $|g|$ is integrable. That is why it is enough to prove that $g \in L^{1}$.
 As for a proof of that, your idea is good, just don't forget $|f|$ - because $f\in L^{1}$, it is easy to bound $||g||$ the way you did.

Comment: I realized that I forgot the $\vert f\vert$ in my calculation, but I don't see how to evaluate the integrals now.

Comment: @cap 
$\int_0^1 \! \int_0^x \! \frac{|f(t)|}{(x-t)^a} \, \mathrm{d}t \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 \! \int_t^1 \! \frac{|f(t)|}{(x-t)^a} \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}t = 
\int_0^1 \! |f(t)| \int_t^1 \! \frac{1}{(x-t)^a} \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}t = 
\int_0^1 \! |f(t)|  \frac{(1-t)^{1-a}}{1-a} \, \mathrm{d}t \leq \frac{1}{1-a}||f||. $

Comment: @cap Also, I have found some nice examples of applying Fubini's theorem that might interest you, the last example is similar to what we did here. https://math.dartmouth.edu/~m13w12/notes/class6.pdf